# How to Stream music into our Android App using Spotify API?

Tags: android, spotify

I'm trying to make an music streaming app using Spotify API, I followed their documentation, and getting response from API.. but I have doubt can we play song inside our Android app using their API? Because I can't see URL into response to play the song..

```
   EndPoint - https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5TDIVbFchsBtI15FvW6eKI
    Response - 
    {
    "album": {
        "album_type": "single",
        "artists": [
            {
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH",
                "id": "5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH",
                "name": "MC STAN",
                "type": "artist",
                "uri": "spotify:artist:5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH"
            }
        ],
        "available_markets": [
            "AD",
            "AE",
            "AL",
            "AR",
            "AT",
            "AU",
            "BA",
            "BE",
            "BG",
            "BH",
            "BO",
            "BR",
            "BY",
            "CA",
            "CH",
            "CL",
            "CO",
            "CR",
            "CY",
            "CZ",
            "DE",
            "DK",
            "DO",
            "DZ",
            "EC",
            "EE",
            "EG",
            "ES",
            "FI",
            "FR",
            "GB",
            "GR",
            "GT",
            "HK",
            "HN",
            "HR",
            "HU",
            "ID",
            "IE",
            "IL",
            "IN",
            "IS",
            "IT",
            "JO",
            "JP",
            "KW",
            "KZ",
            "LB",
            "LI",
            "LT",
            "LU",
            "LV",
            "MA",
            "MC",
            "MD",
            "ME",
            "MK",
            "MT",
            "MX",
            "MY",
            "NI",
            "NL",
            "NO",
            "NZ",
            "OM",
            "PA",
            "PE",
            "PH",
            "PL",
            "PS",
            "PT",
            "PY",
            "QA",
            "RO",
            "RS",
            "RU",
            "SA",
            "SE",
            "SG",
            "SI",
            "SK",
            "SV",
            "TH",
            "TN",
            "TR",
            "TW",
            "UA",
            "US",
            "UY",
            "VN",
            "XK",
            "ZA"
        ],
        "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/1ulRfcW1P501Ge3fq6KvNU"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1ulRfcW1P501Ge3fq6KvNU",
        "id": "1ulRfcW1P501Ge3fq6KvNU",
        "images": [
            {
                "height": 640,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273216b11c58f345e50c78560a6",
                "width": 640
            },
            {
                "height": 300,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02216b11c58f345e50c78560a6",
                "width": 300
            },
            {
                "height": 64,
                "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851216b11c58f345e50c78560a6",
                "width": 64
            }
        ],
        "name": "Tadipaar",
        "release_date": "2021-01-01",
        "release_date_precision": "day",
        "total_tracks": 1,
        "type": "album",
        "uri": "spotify:album:1ulRfcW1P501Ge3fq6KvNU"
    },
    "artists": [
        {
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH",
            "id": "5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH",
            "name": "MC STAN",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:5uemEEtB1ZC3s1KM7gReeH"
        }
    ],
    "available_markets": [
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "AL",
        "AR",
        "AT",
        "AU",
        "BA",
        "BE",
        "BG",
        "BH",
        "BO",
        "BR",
        "BY",
        "CA",
        "CH",
        "CL",
        "CO",
        "CR",
        "CY",
        "CZ",
        "DE",
        "DK",
        "DO",
        "DZ",
        "EC",
        "EE",
        "EG",
        "ES",
        "FI",
        "FR",
        "GB",
        "GR",
        "GT",
        "HK",
        "HN",
        "HR",
        "HU",
        "ID",
        "IE",
        "IL",
        "IN",
        "IS",
        "IT",
        "JO",
        "JP",
        "KW",
        "KZ",
        "LB",
        "LI",
        "LT",
        "LU",
        "LV",
        "MA",
        "MC",
        "MD",
        "ME",
        "MK",
        "MT",
        "MX",
        "MY",
        "NI",
        "NL",
        "NO",
        "NZ",
        "OM",
        "PA",
        "PE",
        "PH",
        "PL",
        "PS",
        "PT",
        "PY",
        "QA",
        "RO",
        "RS",
        "RU",
        "SA",
        "SE",
        "SG",
        "SI",
        "SK",
        "SV",
        "TH",
        "TN",
        "TR",
        "TW",
        "UA",
        "US",
        "UY",
        "VN",
        "XK",
        "ZA"
    ],
    "disc_number": 1,
    "duration_ms": 466285,
    "explicit": true,
    "external_ids": {
        "isrc": "DGA062031741"
    },
    "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5TDIVbFchsBtI15FvW6eKI"
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5TDIVbFchsBtI15FvW6eKI",
    "id": "5TDIVbFchsBtI15FvW6eKI",
    "is_local": false,
    "name": "Tadipaar",
    "popularity": 43,
    "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/d7fefabdb983ee45b960456800fe3cb6a449df3f?cid=9f3ed289582146cdb3f68ab42c5737af",
    "track_number": 1,
    "type": "track",
    "uri": "spotify:track:5TDIVbFchsBtI15FvW6eKI"
}
```

So how to Play track inside our App using Spotify API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preview_url` is a link to a downloadable 30 second mp3 that you can play inside the app.

If you want to play the entire track, you need to enqueue and play it out via the API, using the [player endpoints](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/).

In your case, that could be:

`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri=spotify:track:5TDIVbFchsBtI15FvW6eKI`

Comment: After hit the endpoint response i got, 
{    "error": {
        "status": 403,
        "message": "Player command failed: Premium required",
        "reason": "PREMIUM_REQUIRED"
    }
},   So How developer make cracked version of Spotify and their Apps works fine

Comment: Did you find any solution to play full track?

Comment: No Saurabh. Couldn't find